Is it haram to have friendship with other women after marriage?
My friend is a very religious person, he said that one should not have any relationship with other women after marriage even if it is just friendship? Is this true?

Friendship between unrelated individuals of the opposite gender is prohibited in Islamic teachings. The core guiding principle is the preservation of modesty and the avoidance of situations that may lead to temptation and moral transgression.
The Quranic Surah An-Nur (24:30-31) instructs believers to lower their gaze, emphasizing the importance of maintaining respectful boundaries between genders.
Moreover, numerous Hadith warn against unnecessary mixing between men and women. For example, Prophet Muhammad (SAW) cautioned, "Beware of entering upon women" (Sahih al-Bukhari 5232), stressing the need for caution and restraint in social interactions between genders.
The Hadith stating, "I have not left behind me among the people any fitnah (trial) that is more harmful to men than women" (Sahih al-Bukhari 5096) highlights the potential for sin that can arise from interactions between genders. One guards against this temptation by exercising restraint in relationships between men and women.
For further clarification on this matter, I recommend consulting the following:
Having Contacts with Members of the Opposite Sex
Are Muslim Males Allowed to Have Female Friends?
Friendship Between the Opposite Sexes

^ THE only right answer here. Has its references in place as well.

Sorry for the "spam" message but I would like to draw your attention to the Mod-election.

There is nothing wrong in having healthy relationship with opposite gender. Women during prophet(s.a) used to accompany his companions to help them during their expeditions. Prophet(s.a) used to work with khadeeja (r.a) as a business assistant before he married her.

If only you knew that Khadeeja radiallahu'anha wasn't his (SAW) "friend" before marriage and in fact proposed him (SAW) marriage only via a letter. And only if you knew that the women at the time of Prophet SAW would have completely formal conversations with the men such as in the battleground, for trade, or during a need. Only if you knew that a "friend" is something more than a participant in a formal action.

Your answer either implies that you did not read the question correctly (I hope so) where it clearly talks about friendship and not interaction with the opposite gender entirely, or that you are stating something regarding the companions of the Prophet (May Allah have his peace and blessings upon him, his family, and his companions as well, Aameen) falsely without knowledge. Please correct your answer or correct me if I am wrong.
